# NZEC Error in Python in SPOJ

Tags: python

I think my algo is right(done very badly) But I get the desired outputs in ideone.com. But in SPOJ it keeps on saying "Runtime Error NZEC". Please suggest a few changes to get this right.

Here is the link to the Question :

http://www.spoj.com/problems/LASTDIG/

Here is my code :

```
import sys;
a=dict();
c=dict();
a[1]=[1,1,1,1];
a[2]=[2,4,8,6];
a[3]=[3,9,7,1];
a[4]=[4,6,4,6];
a[5]=[5,5,5,5];
a[6]=[6,6,6,6];
a[7]=[7,9,3,1];
a[8]=[8,4,2,6];
a[9]=[9,1,9,1];
a[10]=[0,0,0,0];
inp=sys.stdin.read().strip().split();
t=int(inp[0]);
readat=1;
for i in xrange(t):
    m,n=map(long,inp[readat:readat+2]);
    r=n%4;
    s=m%10;
    c[i]=a[s][r-1];
    readat=readat+2;
for i in xrange(t):
    print c[i];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first. You are using Python, you DONT have to end the statements with a semi colon ";"! (If you have this habbit from writing a lot of C programs, it's okay!)

Secondly, you shouldn't use 2 for loops when you could do it with just 1. (The print can be executed within the first loop itself, not that this would be the most efficient way though)

The `NZEC` error as you might know stands for `Non Zero Exit Code` which is being returned by Python for your code due to a `KeyError`. Notice how your dictionary `a` has keys 1 to 10 & not `0`? `m%10` would be 0 when s is a multiple of 10. Thus `a[10]` should actually be `a[0]`.

Comment: Now I have Changed to :
Now it gives wrong Answer!
`import sys;
a=dict();
a[1]=[1,1,1,1]
a[2]=[2,4,8,6]
a[3]=[3,9,7,1]
a[4]=[4,6,4,6]
a[5]=[5,5,5,5]
a[6]=[6,6,6,6]
a[7]=[7,9,3,1]
a[8]=[8,4,2,6]
a[9]=[9,1,9,1]
a[0]=[0,0,0,0]
inp=sys.stdin.read();
inp=inp.split();
t=int(inp[0])
readat=1
for i in xrange(t):
    m,n=[inp[readat],inp[readat+1]]
    m,n=[long(m),long(n)]
    if (n==0):
        print '1'
    elif (m==0):
        print '0'
    else :
        r=n%4
        s=m%10
        if(r!=0):
            c=a[s][r-1]
        if(r==0):
            c=a[s][3]
        readat=readat+2
        print c`

Comment: You are forgetting something! (Hint - Exponent = 0) I made the relevant change & got correct answer. You need to handle the exponent = 0 case separately. Reply when you get correct answer! :)

Comment: If you feel my answer is correct then, please "accept" it & close the question.